# Is it possible to use HM-10 or HM-11 BLE Module with Arduino to communicate with an iOS device (ANCS)?

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10, ancs

I would like to build a smartwatch for my iPhone based on the arduino tools and libraries. But I have a problem with BLE: I know there is already a library for the nRF8001 for ancs (https://github.com/robotastic/ANCS-Library) , but I want to use the HM-11 module, mainly because it's smaller and cheaper.
So is it possible to connect an HM-11 module to an Arduino and receive iOS notifications and do something with it? (for example display it on a screen)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't so much an iOS question, as a question of whether `ANCS-Library` can be modified to support the HM-11 (or, indeed, any arbitrary chipset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HMSoft version V524 added ANCS support (not include HMSensor version)

1. How to open ANCS function

1.1 Please read apple notification document first.
1.2 Send `AT+TYPE3` command change to `AUTH` and `BOND` mode.
1.3 Send `AT+ANCS1` command to open `ANCS`.
1.4 Send `AT+PASS`[para1] command to set passcode. Default passcode is "000000"
1.5 Send `AT+RESET` to restart module.

Now you can use LightBlue or our software to scan and made a connect with module. iOS will ask you input passcode. please input your passcode value.
If all is okay,  you should receive `AT+ANCS`[para1] command from module `UART`.

2. About `AT+ANCS[para1]` command 
   `AT+ANCSN`: module open Notification Source SUCCESSED.
   `AT+ANCSC`: module open Control Point SUCCESSED.
   `AT+ANCSD`: module open Data Source SUCCESSED.
3. Get ANCS notification information. When iOS notification center has an change (such as call, email, short message). Module will output `AT+ANCS8[para2]` command through `UART`.
4. About `AT+ANCS8[para2]` command.
   Format such as : `AT+ANCS801012345`
   8: The length of the para1.
   0: `EventID`
   `EventIDNotificationAdded = 0`,
   `EventIDNotificationModified = 1`,
   `EventIDNotificationRemoved = 2`,
   `Reserved EventID values = 3 ~ 255`
   1:`CategoryID`
   `CategoryIDOther = 0`,
   `CategoryIDIncomingCall = 1`,
   `CategoryIDMissedCall = 2`,
   `CategoryIDVoicemail = 3`,
   `CategoryIDSocial = 4`,
   `CategoryIDSchedule = 5`,
   `CategoryIDEmail = 6`,
   `CategoryIDNews = 7`,
   `CategoryIDHealthAndFitness = 8`,
   `CategoryIDBusinessAndFinance = 9`,
   `CategoryIDLocation = 10`,
   `CategoryIDEntertainment = 11`,
   `Reserved CategoryID values = 12 ~ 255`
   01: `CategoryCount`
   The current number of active iOS notifications in the given category. For example, if two unread emails are sitting in a user's email inbox, and a new email is pushed to the user's iOS device, the value of CategoryCount is 3.
   2345: `NotificationUID`
   A 32-bit numerical value that is the unique identifier (UID) for the iOS notification. This value can be used as a handle in commands sent to the Control Point characteristic to retrieve more information about the iOS notification.
5. Get Notification Attributes
   `AT+ANCS[para1][para2][para3]`
   Format such as: `AT+ANCS2345100`

   `para1`: NotificationUID
   `para2`: `NotificationAttributeID`
   `NotificationAttributeIDAppIdentifier = 0`,
   `NotificationAttributeIDTitle = 1`, (Needs to be followed by a 2-bytes max length parameter)
   `NotificationAttributeIDSubtitle = 2`, (Needs to be followed by a 2-bytes max length parameter)
   `NotificationAttributeIDMessage = 3`, (Needs to be followed by a 2-bytes max length parameter)
   `NotificationAttributeIDMessageSize = 4`,
   `NotificationAttributeIDDate = 5`,
   `NotificationAttributeID` = 6 ~ 255
   `para3` : max length parameter (reserved)
   If para2 value is 0, 4, 5, para3 must set to "00"
   if para2 value is 1, 2, 3, you need setup a number.
6. About Get Notification Attributes Response
   `AT+ANCSW`: Send request SUCCESSED.
   `AT+ANCS[para1]:` 
   para1 value is 0x00 ~ 0x14.
   Mean the next package length you need to receive.
   [........]: The byte array you need to receive.
   Show in apple Notification document Figure 2-6. (page 9)
   After you receive AT+ANCSW, you may receive `AT+ANCS[para1]` many times. until the Figure 2-6 package is completed.
7. How to remove ANCS.
   7.1 Remove bond information from iOS.
   7.2 Execute `AT+ERASE` remove module bond information.
   7.3 Execute `AT+ANCS0` close module ANCS function.
   7.4 Execute `AT+RESET` to restart module.

   ANCS is easy to use, you don't need write any iOS code. iOS will manage the bluetooth link and push the message to module.

Answer (score 1):

No, these modules provide serial port emulation over GATT using a service/characteristic.  They do not provide the lower-level access to the Bluetooth stack that is required to implement an ANCS receiver.